# not able to restore tensorflow graph using python3 multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, python-multiprocessing

I want to be able to load an existing tensorflow network simultaneously from several processes using multiprocessing library to do inference on different cores simultaneously.

```
def spawn_process(x):
    g = tf.Graph()
    sess = tf.Session(graph=g)
    with g.as_default():
        meta_graph = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.meta')
        meta_graph.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(chkp_dir)
        x_ph = tf.get_collection('x')[0] # placeholder tensor that we use to pass in new x's to do inference on.
        pred = tf.get_collection('pred')[0] # tensor responsible for computing prediction given x
    prediction = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x_ph: x})
```

This is basically the function I want to pass to `Pool.map` to infer parallely.

Above function works with just `map` and it looks like this

```
predictions = list(map(spawn_process, range(10)))
predictions = [spawn_process(x) for x in range(10)]
```

Both of the above work as expected.

But when I try do this, it fails, and each process just hangs right before the `meta_graph.restore` line and I'm stumped.

```
p = multiprocess.Pool(4)
predictions = p.map(spawn_process, range(10))
p.close()
p.join()
```

I don't know why this isn't working with tensorflow, this normally works for me when I try to do any sort of computation parallely. It stops right before the `meta_graph.restore` line and all the processes hang there.

Comment: what if you move `import tensorflow` inside `spawn_process`?

Comment: actually I was making a script to test everything so that people can help me better.. and in the process I realized I shouldn't have any problem loading checkpoints using multiprocessing. here is the gist and in the comment I described how to test it https://gist.github.com/syllogismos/9079f2bd690b6b861502aefc7c8f5696

but my main script is not working thought, so have to debug whats different with my actual script and this sample logistic regression code

Comment: I am completely stumped, the gist works, but not my script, and I can't tell what's so different, can the place of the import statement make the difference? something to do with global/local scopes? I did try having the import statement inside the function, but it didn't work,

Comment: yes, place of import can make a difference, TensorFlow is known not to be compatible with multiprocessing, but sometimes moving imports around fixes things

Comment: What if other modules that are imported in the file in turn import tensorflow, will it also effect it?

Comment: You will probably do best if you simply launch multiple separate Python processes yourself, rather than trying to use the `multiprocess` library.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did finally, shifted the working multiprocessing code to a simple python http server and talk to it from main program using requests. I thought its quite an ugly way of doing things, but its working now. What should be a straight forward thing, but because of this, i had to use http, pickling things to file system and etc..